# TCPDF problems part 2

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am exporting data into a pdf using TCPDF. Everything works fine until I add a certain column (long text format) to the table. Whenever I add it, the table doesn't show up. When I run the sql query all the data shows up fine.

Is it possible there's a character or characters in the data field itself that are causing the table to become corrupted?

Also I can't for the life of me, figure out how I show more than 256 characters in cell.

If anyone can help I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Try to use iconv php function.

Comment: thanks but I'm not sure what am I converting from.

Answer (score 0):

well until I find a better option I am running this to each of my comment fields

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME set COLUMN_NAME = replace(COLUMN_NAME, '’', '`');
```